# treat with the enemy for peace (is this phrase idiomatic?)

Tags: verb-usage

> treat with the enemy for peace

'treat' is used like: treat people with respect

I wonder if the phrase above is idiomatic or not.

Comment: The phrase doesn't really make sense in its current form.

Maybe it should be `Treat the enemy with respect.`

Comment: @MeltingDog - No, "treat" is a verb meaning "negotiate for a treaty".  James K's answer below is correct.

Comment: I'm assuming that you saw this on [one](https://universal_en_ru.academic.ru/2478386/treat+with+the+enemy+for+peace) of the [various](https://www.zargan.com/tr/q/treat%20with%20the%20enemy%20for%20peace-ceviri-nedir) dictionary [sites](http://dict.cn/treating_2Bwith_2Bwastewater) where this exact phrase appears as an example for translators.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This usage is becoming archaic, but you occasionally see it.  It means "negotiate or make a deal with".  The word "treaty" comes from this sense.

So the meaning of the phrase is not like "treat people with respect", but "negotiate a peace treaty."

Comment: Though it'd be pretty hard getting someone to sign a peace treaty if you *don't* treat them with respect...

Comment: I dunno, The allies didn't treat Nazi Germany with respect in 1945.